# sql server db object create script

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server query to generate script from all the database when a certain pattern matches. For instance script out all the database objects which has "Customer". My environment has few different database.

TestDB
ProdDB
QatDB
DBShare
CustomerEurope
CustomerNA
CustomerAP
CustomerANZ

Let's say I have table, function, view, stored procedure which has name v_customer_na_dbshare view or f_customereurope_qatdb. I would like to have a script which creates these 2 objects in dbshare & qatdb respectively.

Please guide me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a database -> tasks -> generate script.
There you can choose ALL objects which contain word `customer`.
You can easily identify them by following script:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE name like '%customer%'
```

Comment: Hi Slava Murygin, I would like to automate this process.

Comment: You request is very specific. If you are looking for a product, which can do that, than that is not a `programming` question. If you are looking for a SQL script, which will be able to script ANY type of object, then you probably won't find it. And even if it exists, I wouldn't trust it. As you know, sometimes even SSMS has bugs with script generation.